# Binary Search--Doubles and Integers in the Same Array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, double, binary-search

I am taking a Michigan Virtual Online Course about learning Java. We are currently finishing up our study on arrays and one of my tasks is to create a binary search to find the value 45.3. The only problem is that 45.3 isn't read as an integer in the cmd but as a double. How do I formulate my code so that I can include double and integer values within my array? Other classmates are taking this course as well so this will help them if they're stuck.

```
class binarysearcharrayunitproject
{
    public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    public static int binarySearch(Integer [] a, int x)
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.length-1;
        int mid;
        while( low <= high )
        {
             mid = ( low + high ) / 2;


        if( a[mid] .compareTo(x)<0)
                low = mid + 1;
        else if(a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0 )
                    high = mid-1;
        else
                    return mid;
     }
     return NOT_FOUND;
    }


public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          int SIZE = 6;
        Integer[]a= **{-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};**
          System.out.println("45.3 found at " +binarySearch(a, 78));
    }
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have "integers and doubles", then what you really have is just doubles. Use a `Double[]` instead of an `Integer[]`.

In fact you don't seem to need wrappers, so just use `double[]` with `<` and `>` instead of the `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric whole-number literals are compiled as `int` values, and java arrays have exactly one type they store. However, java will automatically *widen* `int` values to `double` when needed, so you can use a `double[]` for your values:

```
double[] a = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};  // compiles OK
```

and change your method signature to:

```
public static int binarySearch(double[] a, int x);
```

Note that you **can't** use `Double[]` (`Double` is the Java wrapper class for a `double`), because while java can automatically widen from `int` to `double` *and* autobox from `double` to `Double`, it won't do *both*, i.e. this line won't compile:

```
Double[] a = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};  // compile error for the int literals!
```